# Link para compartilhar?

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Quando uma pergunta não tem respostas nós vemos o texto para compartilhar a pergunta para alguém responder. Mas nas ações não há o link `compartilhar`.

A imagem a seguir mostra o texto, ações do SOpt, ações do SO:

[image: Share]

Creio que por causa do **closed** beta o link de compartilhar não apareça, mas o texto "Conhece alguém que pode responder..." aparece. Isto é alguma inconsistência? Ou está assim por algum outro motivo?

Seria problema deixar o link "compartilhar" habilitado?

Answer (score 3):

Não posso responder com autoridade mas é quase certo que seja porque estamos em beta privado o motivo de não aparecer o link de compartilhar.

Acho que o **link de compartilhamento seria útil** mesmo para uso interno. Não é o fim do mundo, mas ajudaria pegar a URL de respostas de forma mais fácil.

O site tem algumas inconsistências temporárias mas essa não é grave. Em teoria deveríamos ficar apenas 7 dias em beta fechado e é mais fácil conviver com pequenas inconsistências nesse curto período do que complicar o sistema para lidar com a exceção.

Comment: Mais um argumento a favor de irmos pro beta público também.

Answer (score 3):

Acho que o bigown tem razão, ele deve aparecer quando o site for para o beta público. Tenho construído o link na mão quando preciso, da seguinte maneira:

```
[link-da-pergunta]/id-da-resposta#id-da-resposta
```

O ID da resposta você pode conseguir passando o mouse sobre o link de editar dela. Por exemplo, o link direto para esta resposta é:

```
http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/295/link-para-compartilhar/526#526
```

Comment: Quando eu quero o link de uma resposta, abro o perfil do usuário que a postou e vou na aba "respostas" - copiando e colando o endereço. Entretanto, com o tempo isso ficará impraticável...

Answer (score 2):

De um modo geral, também acho que o link de compartilhar deveria estar disponível. **Entretanto**, como a URL do SOPT vai mudar de `br.stackoverflow.com` para `pt.stackoverflow.com`, qualquer link compartilhado ainda no beta privado vai terminar quebrado quado chegar no beta público...

(Isso não impede as pessoas de compartilharem links de qualquer forma, mas estimular, nesse momento, não me parece uma boa ideia)

O que a equipe do SE poderia fazer é **já criar** o `pt.stackoverflow.com` e - inicialmente - redirecionar pra cá. Assim, o link de compartilhar já usaria a URL nova. Quando mudasse, parava de redirecionar, e os links já compartilhados continuariam valendo.

P.S. Isso não muda o fato que, se alguém que não é cadastrado tentar seguir o link, ele não estará acessível. Isso é um problema, por isso talvez seja melhor deixar as coisas como estão mesmo...

Comment: Boa lembrança sobre a troca do domínio. Vamos precisar fazer um mutirão de edição, a menos que os devs façam um busca-e-troca do lado deles.

Comment: @bfavaretto creio que a solução do pt. como redirect o quanto antes seja uma boa adiantada nesse sentido. Quanto aos links existentes, um search-replace da parte da equipe do SE seria o mais sensato.

Comment: Outra solução é ter o br redirecionando pro pt (acho que é esta a intenção deles), aí nem precisa de busca e troca.